# Are there alternatives to ODBC for MS Access/SQL Server Connection?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, ascii

My question is this: Are there alternatives to ODBC that would allow us to connect our SQL Server to MS Access?

Here's the situation: My company works with a proprietary, SQL database (ProVenue) that up and decided to "no longer support ODBC" to MS Access, our front-end tool, without telling us.

We are currently migrating away from ProVenue, but in the meantime , we're stuck with a vendor, which "no longer supports" our ODBC connection(s). The vendor also has no incentive to help since we're leaving in several months.

I've devised a workaround where I manually export the ProVenue tables (ASCII), proof (yes, the export utiliy pulls unreliably), convert and upload on a daily basis into Access. That said, it is unreasonably time consuming given the number of tables. This work-around could be a full-time job.

Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: If it's just a standard SQL Server database, how can they "no longer support ODBC"?

Comment: why not upload that tables to SQL Server directly?

Answer (score 5):

Do NOT consider using ADP.  It has been dropped from Access 2013 and hence is a technology with no future.

Answer (score 1):

From what you're saying, you don't "own" your own MSSQL database - you're simply connecting to an instance that the provider manages, correct?  I would guess that they've disabled ODBC connections to MSSQL because they don't like the load placed on their servers and/or that they've decided they want to change some underlying structures and don't want to have to cope with anybody whining about those changes.

That said, do they allow direct MSSQL connections?  Via SQL Management Studio, for example?  If so, you should be able to define an export & import process which is less buggy than theirs, and simply re-point your Access database to the local copy of data.  True, this would still require some (possibly automated) import process, so you'd be out of synch with the server, but it'd give you the solution.

You might try connecting an .adp file to the server, to see if they'll still let you access things in that manner.  That would possibly require significant modifications to your Access solution, but would also be a bit easier on their servers than linked tables via ODBC.

Comment: +1 for the SSMS suggestion. For example, you could set up a job that exports your tables as text files to a specific location, and Access can directly reference those files as linked tables, or you could import them.

Comment: Thanks for the +1!  My personal preference would be to migrate to an instance of MSSQL - could even use the freebie version - so as to preserve any keys which are stored in the symbolic links within Access.  It'd just mean re-linking the tables, that way, with a different server name.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at Access Data Projects (ADP) which are tied directly to one SQL Server database. I don't think they use ODBC at all, but they have their own limitations, and of course, aren't available in older Access versions.